# how to send back token after received some eth?

Tags: contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

how to add this functionality into a token contract?
Function : whenever anyone sends any Ethereum to my contract address, any number more than 0 (even an amount like 0.000000001), I would like to send them back 1000 of my tokens, and send eth that can be contracted to a certain address?

Example contract like this : https://etherscan.io/address/0x55732acec59699e28bad93522684e0d241a64a35

thanks

Comment: I've added an example below, but it sounds like you are very new to smart contract development - I would encourage you to read up on some smart contract dev basics to have a better understanding of how they work.

Comment: https://blog.zeppelin.solutions/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-smart-contracts-in-ethereum-848f08001f05 for example; also the one I posted in my answer

Answer (score 4):

One of the best prototypes of ERC20 token implementation is the [OpenZeppelin's ERC20 implementation.](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/BasicToken.sol)

Follow it's guidelines and you'll archive to do it.

Related with your problem, **the error that gives the other answer comes from the ERC20 implementation** , if You've overridden the transfer() method and set only one parameter, you won't be able to do it.

Another problem is that `msg.value` is in wei, so as fas as a wei is indivisible, that may be causing errors too.

So doing it fast it'll be something like that:

```
contract MyToken {
    // ERC20 token implementation
}

contract SomeContract {
    address tokenAddress;
    MyToken token;
    token.approve(this( which is adress of SomeContract), X amount of tokens is able to donate has to be more than 1000 that is what you send)

    // Run this first, to tell the contract the address 
    // of your token smart contract
    function setTokenAddress(address _tokenAddress) public {
        tokenAddress = _tokenAddress;
        token = MyToken(_tokenAddress);
    }

    function GiveMeTokens() public payable {
        if (msg.value > 1) {
            token.transfer(msg.sender, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

**Use a standard ERC20 implementation** and try again your method.

Answer (score 3):

A few preconditions: your token contract is an ERC20 token; the smart contract that gives out tokens, has the tokens transferred to it.

```
contract MyToken {
    // ERC20 token implementation
}

contract SomeContract {
    address tokenAddress;
    MyToken token;    

    // Run this first, to tell the contract the address 
    // of your token smart contract
    function setTokenAddress(address _tokenAddress) public {
        tokenAddress = _tokenAddress;
        token = MyToken(_tokenAddress);
    }

    function GiveMeTokens() public payable {
        if (msg.value > 0.000000001) {
            // Transfer 1000 tokens from smart contract address 
            // to contract caller address
            token.transfer(msg.sender, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested it, just typed it here, so it might not compile but should give you an idea of how to do that.

It will be helpful for your overall understandig to read about ERC20 token smart contracts and how they work. For example https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard

Comment: this contract does not work on the part    :                                    
    function GiveMeTokens() public payable {
        if (msg.value > 0.00000001) {
            // Transfer 1000 tokens from smart contract address 
            // to contract caller address
            token.transfer(msg.sender,1000);
        }
    }

Comment: @gosdorxda - what exactly doesn't work? What error are you getting?

Comment: this error : browser/ballot.sol:20:13: TypeError: Value transfer to a contract without a payable fallback function.
            token.transfer(msg.sender,100);
            ^------------^
browser/ballot.sol:20:13: TypeError: Wrong argument count for function call: 2 arguments given but expected 1.
            token.transfer(msg.sender,100);
            ^----------------------------^